# OFF - É possível imprimir um valor de uma lista passando o índice dele?

Tags: python, lista, loop

No código abaixo eu,quando saio do while,eu imprimo os dados dos saltos do atleta,juntamente com a média dos mesmos. No loop for,eu imprimo todas os saltos do atleta,mas gostaria de saber se consigo buscar as distâncias uma por uma,colocando seu índice. Pois queria fazer algo como no exemlo:

Primeiro salto:5.8

Segundo salto:5.7

Terceiro salto:6.1

E por aí vai

````
distancia =[]
salto = 0

while nome != '':
    nome = input('Insira o nome do atleta:')
    nomes.append(nome)
    if nome == '':
        break;
    for i in range(1,6):
        salto = float(input(f'Informe a distância do {i}º salto do atleta:'))
        distancia.append(salto)
        media = sum(distancia)/len(distancia)
print(f'Atleta:{nome}')
for i in distancia:
    print(i)
print('Resultado final')
print(f'Saltos:{distancia}')
print(f'Média dos saltos:{media}')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível solução para este problema seria:

```
distancia =[]
salto = 0

while nome != '':
    nome = input('Insira o nome do atleta:')
    nomes.append(nome)
    if nome == '':
        break;
    for i in range(1,6):
        salto = float(input(f'Informe a distância do {i}º salto do atleta:'))
        distancia.append(salto)
        media = sum(distancia)/len(distancia)
print(f'Atleta:{nome}')
for i in distancia:
    print(i)
print('Resultado final')
print(f'Saltos: {distancia}')
print(f'Média dos saltos: {media}')
print('Primeiro salto: {}'.format(distancia[0]))
print('Segundo salto: {}'.format(distancia[1]))
print('Terceiro salto: {}'.format(distancia[2]))
```

Repare que em minha solução estou assumindo que existem os 3 índices preenchidos na lista distância.
Caso esta suposição não seja verdadeira, então vai ocorrer um acesso a um endereço de memória inválido.

## Versão iterativa

Pode ser utilizado uma versão iterativa desta mesma abordagem. Neste caso não vou escrever por extenso os valores do salto, irei utilizar o indicador de número ordinal (<kbd>º</kbd>), na função enumerate utilizei o valor `start=1`, pois em python os arrays são indexados a partir do índice zero, desta forma será impresso corretamente o valor para o salto:

```
for num, salto in enumerate(distancia, start=1):
    print("{}º salto: {}".format(num, salto))
```

Desta forma poderíamos ter um quantidade ilimitada de saltos que eles seriam exibidos de maneira apropriada.

Comment: Consegui,obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer exatamente os textos "Primeiro", "Segundo", etc, não há uma maneira direta - pelo menos nativamente - de se obter. O jeito é você mesmo construir os textos, ou usar um módulo externo.

Se optar por construir os textos manualmente, uma alternativa seria ter uma lista com as opções:

```
distancia = # código para preencher a lista é igual ao seu

ordinais = ['Primeiro', 'Segundo', 'Terceiro', 'Quarto', 'Quinto' ]
for i, salto in enumerate(distancia):
    print(f'{ordinais[i]} salto: {salto}')
```

Outra opção, conforme indicada nos comentários, é usar `zip` para percorrer ambas as listas simultaneamente:

```
for ordinal, salto in zip(ordinais, distancia):
    print(f'{ordinal} salto: {salto}')
```

O detalhe é que [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) se encerra quando a menor das listas terminar, então você tem que garantir que há textos suficientes em `ordinais` para que nenhum elemento de `distancia` fique de fora (na verdade, na primeira opção você também tem que garantir isso, senão um salto ficará sem o texto correspondente).

Então outra opção mais geral é usar [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), que é similar a `zip`, mas itera até o final da maior lista, e os elementos faltantes da menor lista são, por *default*, iguais a `None`.  No caso de ter mais saltos do que textos, você poderia colocar o sufixo `º`, como sugeriu a outra resposta (mas caso tenha o texto, use-o):

```
distancia = ...
ordinais = ['Primeiro', 'Segundo', 'Terceiro', 'Quarto', 'Quinto' ]

from itertools import zip_longest

for i, (ordinal, salto) in enumerate(zip_longest(ordinais, distancia), start=1):
    if salto is None: # não há mais saltos, pare o loop
        break
    if ordinal is None: # não há mais textos, usa o número e o sufixo º
        ordinal = f'{i}º'
    print(f'{ordinal} salto: {salto}')
```

---

Mas esta opção é meio limitada, pois se for possível uma quantidade muito grande de saltos, a lista `ordinais` ficará enorme.

Neste caso, outra opção é usar algum módulo externo. Uma alternativa é o [`num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/):

```
from num2words import num2words

for i, salto in enumerate(distancia, start=1):
    print(f'{num2words(i, to="ordinal", lang="pt_BR").capitalize()} salto: {salto}')
```

O detalhe é que este módulo retorna a string com letras minúsculas ("primeiro", "segundo", etc), então eu uso [`capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) para mudar a primeira letra para maiúscula.

Comment: No primeiro exemplo, ao invés de usar o `enumerate` só pra acessar `ordinais` por índice não seria melhor já usar um `zip` direto? Ou um `zip_longest` se o comprimento de `ordinais` for um problema?

Comment: @fernandosavio É mesmo. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado! :-)

Comment: Quase esqueci do +1. ;)